# get the active user email on submit event google form with the option collect email disabled between users with gsuite edutacion accounts

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms

I am developing a script in a google form, which when the user click on submit button, a customized scripts is executed.

In this script i want to capture the email of the person who is sending the google form but I don't get it.

I am using google accounts that belongs to a g suite education organization.

I have disabled the option "collect email", because i don't want that the user insert manually his address email, i want that the system take it automatically.

Here the code that i have in the script that it is executed when the user click on submit button:

```
function onFormSubmit() {
 var eMail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();  
 Logger.log(eMail);
```

}

I also tried this another implementation:

```
function onFormSubmit() {
  var formURL = FormApp.getActiveForm().getEditUrl();
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formURL);
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  var lastResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length-1];
  var eMail = lastResponse.getRespondentEmail()
  Logger.log(eMail);
}
```

Both of them are not working, they return an empty field.

I appreciate if someone could help me.

Thanks very much

Comment: Read this: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user#getEmail()

Comment: Also, ````getRespondentEmail()```` would always return empty because you have disabled email collection. Read this: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getrespondentemail.